# Contoso university

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a 27" screen and with a 1/2 - 2/3 screen size page, and everything looks good. The instructor fields are centered with proportionate padding (about 1") on either side and the Course checkboxes and courses are in a 3 column table (albeit too narrow to fit the courses) . As soon as I increase the page width past 2/3 of the screen, the Instructor fields shrink to about 1/3 their original size, and are left justified. The checkboxes and courses become stacked with the exception of the "1045 Calculus cell", which remains ok probably due to its size.

2/3 screen page width: X=checkbox.

```
X 1045 Calculus     X 1050 Chemistry   X 2021 Composition
X 2042 Literature   X 3141 TrigonometryX 4022 Microeconomics
X 4041 Macroeconomics
```

Greater than 2/3 screen page width looks like the following:
Textboxes shrink to about 1/3 above size.

```
X 1045 Calculus    X 1050       X 2021
                   Chemistry    Composition
X 2042 Literature  X 3141       X 4022
                   Trigonometry Microeconomics
X 4041
Macroeconomics
```

Why is this happening? I've tried various bootstrap col-md settings and I cannot vary the width of the columns until I increase 2/3 screen size and then everything goes haywire. Other than this, the app works fine.
I'm new to bootstrap code and razor pages and would appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance

Added corrected code. Note the 2nd line where I changed the number from "col-md-4" to "col-md-10". I initially changed the "col" definitions in the form-group for the checkboxes, and should have realized that the whole page was affected.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10">
    <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Instructor.ID" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Instructor.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Instructor.LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Instructor.FirstMidName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Instructor.FirstMidName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.FirstMidName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Instructor.HireDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Instructor.HireDate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.HireDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.Location" 
                class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.Location"
                class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Instructor.OfficeAssignment.Location"
                class="text-danger" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-12">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        @{
                            int cnt = 0;

                            foreach (var course in Model.AssignedCourseDataList)
                            {
                                if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                                {
                                    @:</tr><tr> </tr><tr>
                                }
                                @:<td>
                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                           name="selectedCourses"
                                           value="@course.CourseID"
                                           @(Html.Raw(course.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                           @course.CourseID @:  @course.Title
                                @:</td>
                            }
                                         @:</tr>
                        }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, show us an example of code that demonstrates your problem ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Textual description is fine, but it doesn't help us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: See the revised code above.